# Поиск ключей в многомерном словаре

Tags: python, словари

Есть словарь:

```
mydict = { 1:{'name':'Joe', 'pos':'xy'}, 
           2:{'name':'Alex', 'pos':'xz'}, 
           3:{'name':'Sue', 'pos':'yz'}}
```

Необходимо найти в этом словаре все ключи 'pos' и составить список их значений.

но значения должны находится в очерёдности заданной числовым ключом:
1- xy, 2- xz, 3- yz 
то есть на выходе должно получиться:

```
mylist = ['xy', 'xz', 'yz']
```

Примерно так как надо, работает вот это:

```
from itertools import groupby

mydict = [{'name':'Joe', 'pos':'xy'}, 
          {'name':'Alex', 'pos':'xz'}, 
          {'name':'Sue', 'pos':'yz'}]

r = groupby(mydict, key=lambda x: x['pos'])

for key, group in r:
     print(key)
```

вот как это в идеале должно выглядеть, но это для списка словарей, а мне нужен словарь содержащий словари

Comment: Что вы хотите получить на выходе- список или словарь словарей?

Comment: на выходе должен получиться список значений ключей словарей словаря ))))) прошу прощения за абра-кадабру. У меня уже есть словарь словарей, мне нужно получить из него значения определённых ключей в виде списка

Comment: Т.е. на выходе нужен `mylist`?

Comment: да , совершенно верно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
res = [v['pos'] for k,v in sorted(mydict.items())]
```

или с использованием модуля Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

res = pd.DataFrame(mydict).T.sort_index()['pos'].tolist()
```

---

оба решения вернут одинаковый результат:

```
print(res)
# ['xy', 'xz', 'yz']
```

Comment: можно в строкн интерпритатора, пожалуйста?

Comment: да, огромное спасибо. именно так. всё работает